# Multiple WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter in Spring Boot not working together

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I have a Spring Boot application. It has 2 `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`s, one of which is inside a Spring library dependency (which is common to other applications):

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.mycomp.common.security.**")
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class CommonWebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
  http
            
            .authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/configurations/**").hasAnyAuthority(TechnicalScope.ACTUATOR_ADMIN.getValue(), SystemScope.ACTUATOR_ADMIN.getValue())
    .antMatchers(GET, "/jobs/scheduling/**").hasAuthority(TechnicalScope.JOB_READ.getValue())
    .antMatchers(GET, "/odata.svc/**").hasAuthority(TechnicalScope.ODATA_READ.getValue())
            
}
```

The second one:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.mycomp.accounts.**.security")
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE + 1)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
  http
        
        .authorizeRequests()
            
            .mvcMatchers(GET, "/swagger-ui.html").permitAll()
            .mvcMatchers(GET, "/webjars/springfox-swagger-ui/**").permitAll()
            .mvcMatchers(GET, "/swagger-resources/**").permitAll()
            .mvcMatchers(GET, "/v2/api-docs/**").permitAll()

            .mvcMatchers(GET, AccountController.BASE_PATH).hasAuthority(Scope.ACCOUNT_READ.getValue())
            .mvcMatchers(PATCH, AccountController.BASE_PATH).hasAuthority(Scope.ACCOUNT_UPDATE.getValue())
    .and()
                .oauth2ResourceServer()
                .jwt()
                .jwtAuthenticationConverter(getJwtAuthoritiesConverter());
            
}
```

Problem: requests are validated against the matchers of the first `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` **ONLY**. The 2nd matchers are ignored.
Trying to debug, I can see `FilterSecurityInterceptor.obtainSecurityMetadataSource` maintains `requestMap` with only 1st Configurer matchers.

**Note**:

1. when moving all matchers of the 1st Configurer into the 2nd one, things work as expected.
2. Both configurers are scanned during startup.

Any idea why only 1st Configurer is being considered in `FilterSecurityInterceptor`?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing a call to `requestMatchers` in `CommonWebSecurityConfig`.

Try doing this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.mycomp.common.security.**")
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class CommonWebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
  http.requestMatchers()
    .antMatchers("/configurations/**").hasAnyAuthority(TechnicalScope.ACTUATOR_ADMIN.getValue(), SystemScope.ACTUATOR_ADMIN.getValue())
    .antMatchers(GET, "/jobs/scheduling/**").hasAuthority(TechnicalScope.JOB_READ.getValue())
    .antMatchers(GET, "/odata.svc/**").hasAuthority(TechnicalScope.ODATA_READ.getValue())
    .authorizeRequests();
}
```

Here is the java doc of `requestMatchers`:

> Allows specifying which HttpServletRequest instances this HttpSecurity
> will be invoked on. This method allows for easily invoking the
> HttpSecurity for multiple different RequestMatcher instances. If only
> a single RequestMatcher is necessary consider using
> mvcMatcher(String), antMatcher(String), regexMatcher(String), or
> requestMatcher(RequestMatcher). Invoking requestMatchers() will not
> override previous invocations of mvcMatcher(String)},
> requestMatchers(), antMatcher(String), regexMatcher(String), and
> requestMatcher(RequestMatcher).

Comment: You can't call hasAnyAuthority() or permitAll() in the setup you mentioned. it does not compile.

Comment: Add `.and()`, like this: 

`http.requestMatchers().antMatchers("/url1", "/url2").and().mvcMatcher(...)`